Printing Label Issue via RDP: Infinite Upload and ~HS in Files.spl
I need to print labels from an RDP session on my PC for testing purposes. It's important to note that printing, whether via RJ45 (Ethernet) or USB, works perfectly from my PC. However, when printing from the RDP session, things get complicated. My label prints, but an infinite upload starts, causing the received folder to grow endlessly, although its size does not change on the RDP side. The file located at C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS becomes huge and contains a series of ~HS.
I started 2 prints just one was completed as we can see in these 2 photos
RDP
D
the resulting spl file looks like this
C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS

CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA
~TA000
~JSN
^LT0
^MNW
^MTT
^PON
^PMN
^LH0,0
^JMA
^PR4,4
~SD15
^JUS
^LRN
^CI27
^PA0,1,1,0
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW602
^LL1193
^LS0
^FT100,1154^A0B,42,43^FH\^CI28^FDNoPesee^FS^CI27
^FT200,1154^A0B,42,43^FH\^CI28^FDTournée^FS^CI27
^FT200,666^A0B,42,43^FH\^CI28^FDOrdre^FS^CI27
^BY8,3,176^FT549,1158^BCB,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^BY5,3,169^FT547,76^BCI,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^FPH,8^FT93,941^A@B,32,31,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FPH,6^FT193,941^A@B,32,31,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FT193,550^A@B,32,31,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FT93,670^A@B,32,36,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FT284,1158^A@B,45,54,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS
~HS

with many more HS than his
the file to send is as follows
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
##�                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ZPL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ��                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ^XA
~TA000
~JSN
^LT0
^MNW
^MTT
^PON
^PMN
^LH0,0
^JMA
^PR4,4
~SD15
^JUS
^LRN
^CI27
^PA0,1,1,0
^XZ
##                            ^XA
^MMT
^PW602
^LL1193
^LS0
^FT100,1154^A0B,42,43^FH\^CI28^FDNoPesee^FS^CI27
^FT200,1154^A0B,42,43^FH\^CI28^FDTournée^FS^CI27
^FT200,666^A0B,42,43^FH\^CI28^FDOrdre^FS^CI27
^BY8,3,176^FT549,1158^BCB,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^BY5,3,169^FT547,76^BCI,,N,N
^FH\^FD>;123456789012^FS
^FPH,8^FT93,941^A@B,32,31,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FPH,6^FT193,941^A@B,32,31,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FT193,550^A@B,32,31,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FT93,670^A@B,32,36,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^FT284,1158^A@B,45,54,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDtest 1^FS^CI27
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
##  ##  

